# initialize() not being called in ViewHolder that implements Toroplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a ViewHolder in my recyclerView that implements Toroplayer:

```
internal class CommunityPlayableViewHolder(itemView: View) : FeedViewHolder(itemView), ToroPlayer, ToroPlayer.EventListener, ToroPlayer.OnErrorListener {

    private val exoPlayerView: PlayerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toroPlayerView)
    private val volumeView: AppCompatImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.volumeIv)
    private val audioManager = itemView.context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    private var helper: ExoPlayerViewHelper? = null
    private var videoUrl: String? = null


    fun bindCommunityVideoOffer(model: CommunityOffer) {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: binding video with url:${model.mediaVideoUriDash}")
    }

    private fun toggleVolume(volumeView: AppCompatImageView) {

        exoPlayerView.player?.let {
            if (helper?.volume == 0f && requestAudioFocus()) {
                helper?.volume = 1f

                volumeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_volume_on)
            } else {

                helper?.volume = 0f
                releaseAudioFocus()
                volumeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_volume_off)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestAudioFocus(): Boolean {
        val result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(null, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)

        return result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED
    }

    private fun releaseAudioFocus() {
        audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(null)
    }


    private fun showPlayer(showVolume: Boolean) {

        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: showPlayer() called")
        exoPlayerView.show()
        if (showVolume) volumeView.show() else volumeView.hide()
    }

    override fun getPlayerView() = this.exoPlayerView

    override fun getCurrentPlaybackInfo(): PlaybackInfo {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: getCurrentPlaybackInfo() called")
        return helper?.latestPlaybackInfo ?: PlaybackInfo()
    }


    override fun initialize(container: Container, playbackInfo: PlaybackInfo) {

        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: initialized() called")

        videoUrl?.let { url ->
            (helper
                    ?: ExoPlayerViewHelper(this, Uri.parse(url)).also {
                        helper = it
                    }).initialize(container, playbackInfo)
            helper?.addPlayerEventListener(this)
            helper?.addErrorListener(this)
            val isMute = currentPlaybackInfo.volumeInfo.isMute
            volumeView.setImageResource(if (isMute) R.drawable.ic_volume_off else R.drawable.ic_volume_on)
        }
    }

    override fun play() {

        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: play() called")
        helper?.play()
    }

    override fun pause() {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: pause() called")
        helper?.pause()
    }

    override fun isPlaying(): Boolean {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: isPlaying() called")
        return helper?.isPlaying ?: false
    }

    override fun release() {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: release() called")
        exoPlayerView.unshow()
        communityPlayableIv.show()
        helper?.removePlayerEventListener(this)
        helper?.removeErrorListener(this)
        helper?.release()
        helper = null
    }

    override fun wantsToPlay(): Boolean {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: wantsToPlay() called")
        val parent = itemView.parent as Container
        if (isLastPlayableItem(parent)) {
            parent.playerSelector = PlayerSelector.DEFAULT_REVERSE
            return ToroUtil.visibleAreaOffset(this, parent) >= 0.8f
        } else {
            parent.playerSelector = PlayerSelector.DEFAULT
        }

        val visibleAreaOffset = if (countPlayableItems(parent) <= 1) 0.2f else 0.8f
        return ToroUtil.visibleAreaOffset(this, itemView.parent) >= visibleAreaOffset
    }

    override fun getPlayerOrder() = adapterPosition

    override fun onBuffering() {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: onBuffering() called")
        exoPlayerView.player?.repeatMode = Player.REPEAT_MODE_ONE
    }

    override fun onFirstFrameRendered() {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: firstFrameRendered() called")
        communityPlayableIv.unshow()
    }

    override fun onPlaying() {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: onPlaying() called")
        SDKEventUtil.CommunityTiles.trackCommunityTileVideoStarted(communityTileId
                ?: "", type?.name?.toLowerCase() ?: "")
        val hasAudio = isAudioTrackAvailable(exoPlayerView.player)
        showPlayer(hasAudio)
        volumeView.setOnClickListener { toggleVolume(it as AppCompatImageView) }
    }

    override fun onPaused() {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: onPaused() called")
        volumeView.setOnClickListener(null)
    }

    override fun onCompleted() {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: onCompleted() called")
        SDKEventUtil.CommunityTiles.trackCommunityTileVideoFinished(communityTileId
                ?: "", type?.name?.toLowerCase() ?: "")
    }

    override fun onError(error: Exception?) {
        Timber.d("PlayableHolder: onError() called")
        SDKEventUtil.CommunityTiles.trackCommunityTileVideoFailed(communityTileId
                ?: "", type?.name?.toLowerCase() ?: "")
    }
}
```

in xml:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
           android:id="@+id/toroPlayerView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:background="@color/transparent"
           android:visibility="invisible"
           app:controller_layout_id="@layout/v_player_controls"
           app:keep_content_on_player_reset="true"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/actionBarPlayable"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/communityPlayableIv"
           app:player_layout_id="@layout/toro_exo_player_view"
           app:resize_mode="zoom"
           app:show_buffering="when_playing"
           app:shutter_background_color="@android:color/transparent"
           app:surface_type="texture_view"
           app:use_controller="false" />
```

The video is not playing, and the initialize() method from Toroplayer is not even being called. The bind method is This has happened spontaneously, and as far as I can tell this ViewHolder is indistinguishable from a previous one I recalled from git which works. I have never updated Toroplayer from

```
implementation "im.ene.toro3:toro:3.7.0.2905-A1"
    implementation "im.ene.toro3:toro-ext-exoplayer:3.7.0.2905-A1"
```

Nor have I updated my Exoplayer dependencies

```
   implementation("com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:'2.10.4') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}

implementation(
        "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.10.4") {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my implementation here? Why does this not work?

Comment: Hey, author of Toro here. I do not have enough time to fix the issue of Toro, if you can please consider https://github.com/eneim/kohii which is a better alternative.

Regarding this question, please make sure you use the `Container` as the RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

My recyclerView containing the video items was initialized as a RecyclerView instead of the Container class that comes with the Toro library, and I wasn't calling setPlayerInitializer on that view in my Fragment

Comment: same issue i am facing can you please help me how to fix this issue